# iPod Touch stuck in Recovery mode

Tags: itunes, ipod-touch, jailbreak, restart, ios

I am using iPod Touch 5G and I've recently jailbroken it.

First, all my apps disappeared from the springboard. 
But now the iPod is stuck in recovery mode. I get a 9006 error when I try to restore it via iTunes.

I've searched online and found a few answers, but none of them work.

Comment: @Robuust okay so awesome people can edit other's questions. But I think it would be nice if you mentioned that I put it in recovery mode due to a restart loop which happened after I did a respring from Bytafont. I'm a novice here, but just saying.

Comment: Irrelevant how you got it actually, we've to get you out.(: do you have a mac or windows? And what version do you have?

Comment: windows xp here. btw, i googled and found a site offering ios downloads, the .ipsw format. i'm downloading that right now. hope it works. it said i could make itunes use that file instead of the one itunes downloads on its own.

Comment: here's the site: http://www.icj.me/ios/all#iPod51

Comment: Could you navigate to \Documents and Settings\username\Application Data\Apple Computer\iTunes\iPhone Software Updates -> Remove the IPSW there and download it again from iTunes. External sources can always be messed with.

Comment: Can you add the answers you've already tried without success? This could prevent people from proposing the same answers again and also help in getting a better understanding of the problem you are facing.

Comment: @patrix stuff I've tried: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5432514?tstart=0

I haven't tried 6 and 7 due to lack of logistics.

Comment: @Robuust I've tried that one.

Answer (score -1):

go on the internet and type in find my ipod but then once you have done that type in your apple ID then take it out of recovery mode hopefully that should work

Comment: The internet is a big area, can you be a bit more specific about the procedure you are recommending here?